# Windows Integrated Security with Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, tomcat6, integrated-security

I'm have the next scenario on my enviroment

- Tomcat running as services in Windows server
- The service is configured with a Domain Account, it is an Active Directory Account.

Now in a Spring Controller I need to acces to a site, this site is configured with Integrated Security.
So what I want is to access to this site using the same credentials that is running the tomcat account. So I'm beleave thath I need to access to this credentials and pass it to a http client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways you can integrate a Java application into an Active Directory / Windows Authentication system:

I would start by understanding the Kerberos and NTLM authentication systems (and which apply to your environment) and reading up on the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html

Given you are using Spring already, I would strongly consider using Spring Security, which has NTLM support: http://blog.mediasoft.be/ntlm-with-spring-security-20/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know that, but I dont want to secure my Web Server, I want to use the windows account used to run the Tomcat Services, like JDBC of MSSQL does if uses IntegratedSecurity in the URL database connection, it will use the user credentials that is running the Tomcat. I'll like to open a http connection inside the server with the service user credentials, but it should by transparnet no user and password on the code.